# Find and retrieve associated value from a PowerShell hash table

Tags: powershell

```
$netshGet = "netsh.exe int ipv4 sh int"
```

Output:

```
Write-Host $netshGet.ScriptOutput

Idx    Met    MTU        State        Name
---  ------  ----------  -----------  -----------------
  1      50  4294967295  connected    Loopback
 19      10        1500  connected    Named-Interface-1
 20      10        1500  connected    Named-Interface-2
```

In my script, I know the name of the interface which is "Named-Interface-1".

What I need to know and what I need to retrieve from this table is its associated "Idx" value. Ultimately I want the value to be in a variable so the only thing that is in the variable is "19", i.e:

```
Write-Host $idx
19
```

Is there a way to search this table for the Idx value Where-Object{ $_.Name -eq 'Named-Interface-1' } ?

Comment: What yo uhave there is just an array a strings returned from netsh.exe.  You'll need to parse that text for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression seems to work for me.

```
 $AdapterName = 'Wi-fi';
 $output = (netsh.exe int ipv4 sh int) -join "`n";
 ([Regex]"(?<idx>\d+)(?=.*$AdapterName)").matches($output)[0].Value
```

Here is the output from the netsh.exe command:

```
Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  3           5        1500  disconnected  Ethernet
  1          50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 11          25        1500  connected     Wi-fi
 12           5        1500  disconnected  Local Area Connection* 2
```

All you should need to do is modify the value of the `$AdapterName` variable, and run the code.

Comment: Brilliant, this worked perfect! Thank you for the complete code and example.